# Unable to add dynamic values in jQuery query builder

Tags: jquery, ajax, query-builder

I just want to add values in select box dynamically in jQuery query builder but I keep getting an error:

> JSON.parse(data.CancerTypeList).forEach(function(index, val)

Code I use for this:

```
var that = this;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: location.protocol + "//" + location.host + appContext,
    data: "command=CaseServices&action=getCanTypeByDiseaseSubTypeId&diseaseSubType=" + 2,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        JSON.parse(data.CancerTypeList).forEach(function(index, val) {
            that.addOption(val.CancerTypeName);
        });
    }
});
```

From ajax I got 200 but values not added in select. please help

Comment: what does the response look like?

Comment: Examine your 'data' variable value. Are you getting valid Array from backend response ?

Comment: i use jquery query builder my req. is like when i select option from 1 table another options come into another table ....

Comment: yes i got valid response

Comment: in plugin they do somthing like `JSON.parse(localStorage.demoData).forEach(function(item) {
            that.addOption(item);`

Comment: you show you demo data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters according to server is

```
command=CaseServices
action=getCanTypeByDiseaseSubTypeId
diseaseSubType= 2
```

Is this what you need

can you take a screen shot of the object received in the jquery